# Escaping multiline wordpress shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

How to escape multiline wordpress shortcode?

```
[accordion_item title="Item 2"]
item content
[/accordion_item]
```

We could use double brakets, but "/" sign brokes everything. Can't belive WP guys lost this case (

```
[[accordion_item title="Item 3"]]
item content
[[accordion_item]]
```

this works, but code below doesn't escaped properly

```
[[accordion_item title="Item 3"]]
item content
[[/accordion_item]]
```

Don't want to replace manually brakets with html codes. (and WP automatically get them back after user switch editor mode to visual)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Function get_shortcode_regex() in shortcodes.php makes all logic with escaping shortcodes parsing (capture group 1 and 5)

For example with 

`[[new_something my_attr="test"]And have content!! [vc_tabs][/vc_tabs][/new_something]]`

After preg_match_all you will get that
first capture group is not empty and it is "[" (so you can know that this shortcode is not for rendering)

second capture group will show shortcode name "new_something"

third capture group will show everything in attributes `" my_attr="test""`

four capture group will show content `And have content!! [vc_tabs][/vc_tabs]`

Five capture group will show that escape characters has at end.

Basically this means that all information is known when you write escape like this: `[[your_shortcode]content[/your_shortcode]]`

Answer (score 0):

the Answer: replacing [ by `&#91;` and ] by `&#93;`

Link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33960/how-do-i-escape-a-in-a-short-code

Side Note:

Wysiwyg <=> text transition causing html encoding is, and always be a problem.  I would recommend just getting rig of the visual editor all together!

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but as i wrote, i'm trying to find another solution.